# In an Angular project using the CLI and Sass, how can I see the compiled component CSS?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

In our Angular 10 project, we use Sass for all of our component stylesheets. Angular compiles the Sass, then delivers the stylesheets via javascript.

This is great, except when it comes time to inspect our compiled CSS to see where there might be inefficiencies in our Sass. I get size warning when I build the project that certain stylesheets are over budget, but I know of no way to see those stylesheets in CSS form to understand why we are going over budget, and where there is room to improve.

I believe that the stylesheets pass through a "css" phase in the angular build process--is there any way to capture those so I can inspect those files directly?

Comment: I think you can achieve something like that uing [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) and a custom webpack config. I have never done that before, but I have writen a few Schematics using custom webpack config.

Comment: also read this article [Multiple CSS bundles with webpack](https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09).

Comment: Hmm... Ideally, I'm not trying to put together a new build system, I just want a peak at the files that are already being created (I believe). But I'll take a look. Thanks for the suggestion.